# Capturing webpage as image in c#, ensuring javascript rendered elements are visible

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, highcharts

I am trying to capture the following page using standard c# .net code.  I've searched around for people's various methods, most of which involve instantiating a browser object and using a draw to bitmap method.  However, none of these pick up the contents of the chart on this page:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

Perhaps the javascript doesn't have time to run, but adding Thread.Sleep(x) hasn't assisted.

This [commercial component](http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/) captures it correctly, but I'd rather avoid requiring an additional dependency in my project and paying $150 when the other solutions are sooo close!.

Anyone find their solution renders this correctly?

Comment: Linking a related question: [How to fix a opacity bug with DrawToBitmap on WebBrowser Control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697048/how-to-fix-a-opacity-bug-with-drawtobitmap-on-webbrowser-control/21828265#21828265).

Comment: Thought I'd add a comment here, since I still see attention on it all this time later.  In the end there were quite a few edge cases formatting wise, etc, and I decided I needed PDF versions.  I ended up using EssentialObjects PDF control which is excellent for the purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have possibly tried [IECapt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iecapt/). I think it is the right way to go. I created a modified version of it and use a `timer` instead of `Thread.Sleep` it captures your site as expected.

**------EDIT------**

Here is the ugly source. Just Add a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`.

And this is the usage:

```
HtmlCapture capture = new HtmlCapture(@"c:\temp\myimg.png");
capture.HtmlImageCapture += new HtmlCapture.HtmlCaptureEvent(capture_HtmlImageCapture);
capture.Create("http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes");

void capture_HtmlImageCapture(object sender, Uri url)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

File1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace MyIECapt
{
    public class HtmlCapture
    {
        private WebBrowser web;
        private Timer tready;
        private Rectangle screen;
        private Size? imgsize = null;

        //an event that triggers when the html document is captured
        public delegate void HtmlCaptureEvent(object sender, Uri url);

        public event HtmlCaptureEvent HtmlImageCapture;

        string fileName = "";

        //class constructor
        public HtmlCapture(string fileName)
        {
            this.fileName = fileName;

            //initialise the webbrowser and the timer
            web = new WebBrowser();
            tready = new Timer();
            tready.Interval = 2000;
            screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            //set the webbrowser width and hight
            web.Width = 1024; //screen.Width;
            web.Height = 768; // screen.Height;
            //suppress script errors and hide scroll bars
            web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            web.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            //attached events
            web.Navigating +=
              new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(web_Navigating);
            web.DocumentCompleted += new
              WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(web_DocumentCompleted);
            tready.Tick += new EventHandler(tready_Tick);
        }


        public void Create(string url)
        {
            imgsize = null;
            web.Navigate(url);
        }

        public void Create(string url, Size imgsz)
        {
            this.imgsize = imgsz;
            web.Navigate(url);
        }



        void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender,
                 WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //start the timer
            tready.Start();
        }

        void web_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            //stop the timer   
            tready.Stop();
        }



        void tready_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //stop the timer
                tready.Stop();

                mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 docs2 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)web.Document.DomDocument;
                mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 docs3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)web.Document.DomDocument;
                mshtml.IHTMLElement2 body2 = (mshtml.IHTMLElement2)docs2.body;
                mshtml.IHTMLElement2 root2 = (mshtml.IHTMLElement2)docs3.documentElement;

                // Determine dimensions for the image; we could add minWidth here
                // to ensure that we get closer to the minimal width (the width
                // computed might be a few pixels less than what we want).
                int width = Math.Max(body2.scrollWidth, root2.scrollWidth);
                int height = Math.Max(root2.scrollHeight, body2.scrollHeight);

                //get the size of the document's body
                Rectangle docRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

                web.Width = docRectangle.Width;
                web.Height = docRectangle.Height;

                //if the imgsize is null, the size of the image will 
                //be the same as the size of webbrowser object
                //otherwise  set the image size to imgsize
                Rectangle imgRectangle;
                if (imgsize == null) imgRectangle = docRectangle;
                else imgRectangle = new Rectangle() { Location = new Point(0, 0), Size = imgsize.Value };

                //create a bitmap object 
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imgRectangle.Width, imgRectangle.Height);
                //get the viewobject of the WebBrowser
                IViewObject ivo = web.Document.DomDocument as IViewObject;

                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    //get the handle to the device context and draw
                    IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
                    ivo.Draw(1, -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,
                             IntPtr.Zero, hdc, ref imgRectangle,
                             ref docRectangle, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                    g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
                }
                //invoke the HtmlImageCapture event
                bitmap.Save(fileName);
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }
            catch 
            {
                //System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            }
            if(HtmlImageCapture!=null) HtmlImageCapture(this, web.Url);
        }
    }
}
```

and File2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyIECapt
{
    [ComVisible(true), ComImport()]
    [GuidAttribute("0000010d-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IViewObject
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [PreserveSig]
        int Draw(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 dwDrawAspect,
            int lindex,
            IntPtr pvAspect,
            [In] IntPtr ptd,
            IntPtr hdcTargetDev,
            IntPtr hdcDraw,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref Rectangle lprcBounds,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref Rectangle lprcWBounds,
            IntPtr pfnContinue,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 dwContinue);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetColorSet([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwDrawAspect,
           int lindex, IntPtr pvAspect, [In] IntPtr ptd,
            IntPtr hicTargetDev, [Out] IntPtr ppColorSet);
        [PreserveSig]
        int Freeze([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwDrawAspect,
                        int lindex, IntPtr pvAspect, [Out] IntPtr pdwFreeze);
        [PreserveSig]
        int Unfreeze([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwFreeze);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks LB.  I did try this earlier and the command line version worked well.  However it requires a system COM DLL so when trying to put it in a project I couldn't get it to compile for love nor money!  Calling the command line is another option but not as desirable as just calling a method.  Did you get it running in a project or just do the command line?  If you did, perhaps you can share a snippet of how you got that DLL working, or a link to an example?  Many thanks!

Comment: I am trying to use your code and put all stuff into DLL and I am facing this error: ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment. It is here:  public HtmlCapture(string fileName)
        {
            this.fileName = fileName;

            //initialise the webbrowser and the timer
            web = new WebBrowser(); // ERROR

Comment: @AlonM I posted the whole code. What do you want more?

Comment: It does seems not to work for me, what do i need to copy and where, sorry for been a dumb one, but i dont understand where to put what.

Comment: Why been so rude when you can just expline?

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Sleep` will simply suspend the thread your web browser is running on - how do you expect it to render anything when it is suspended? :)

Instead, you need to allow the thread to process work. You can achieve this with a combination of `Thread.Sleep(0)` and `Application.DoEvents()`, with something like the following:

```
DateTime finish = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(3);
while (DateTime.Now < finish) {
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@L.B , thank you for the help!

Just an FYI for anyone wanting to run it in a class library,
WebBrowser needs to Single Threaded Apartment, so do something like this:

```
  var t = new Thread(InitAndDo); //InitAndDo would have your code creating the webbrowser object etc...
  t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  t.Start();
```

Then the Gotcha, after the navigate call is done, add this line of code so that you get the completed navigation event:

```
    web.Navigate(Url);
    Application.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a nuget package for this purpose
https://github.com/dcumin39/RenderHighCharts/wiki