# How to get full height of web page in WebKit Browser

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webkit

I'm trying to take full height of a web page in WebKit Browser. `Document.Bounds.Height` doesn't work, `Document.Height` doesn't work, `Document.ClientSize.Height` doesn't work, `Document.Bottom` doesn't work. They all depend on the size of the window.

P.S.: I'm trying to capture **snapshot of a web page**, I just need sizes of the web page as Width and Height after navigating the page via WebKit Browser Control, the rest is easy. 
Btw, I couldn't find any useful information about WebKit.Interop; if there is a trick for this operation, please let me know.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7803330/932418

Comment: Thanks for link, but I just need sizes of web page in WebKit Browser.

Comment: I found the answer, I will write tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

To scroll down to the end of the page, following code can be used:

```
   int prevx;
   WebKit.WebBrowser browser;    //Assume created by drag-and-drop.
   while(true) {
      prevx = browser.ScrollOffset.X;
      browser.ScrollOffset = new Point(prevx+1000,0);
      if(prevx == browser.ScrollOffset.X) 
            break;
   }
```

So now, browser.ScrollOffset.X will return final scroll offset. By following code, we can take  total width of a web page:

```
   int totalHeight = browser.ScrollOffset.X + browser.Width;
```

Same process should be done for **Height**, in **Y-axis**.