# Print a webpage with a watermark

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capturing webpage as image in c#, ensuring javascript rendered elements are visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803201/capturing-webpage-as-image-in-c-ensuring-javascript-rendered-elements-are-visi)

I am trying on a project to allow the web page to be printed when clicked on a print button, and change the webpage that I am going to print into an image so that I could try watermark. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably hire a .NET developer if you need help ASAP. Stack Overflow is not a good place for such kind of questions. If you expect to get help here you should show what you have tried so far and what difficulties have you encountered.

Comment: You are aware that you can't stop the user from printing your site with Ctrl+P.. Why not just add a background image that looks like a water mark on the page when the user prints. This can be done with the media setting in CSS http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Comment: There is a javascript library thats render the full html page to an image, maybe after this you can add your watermark. Check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6789627/159270  Of cource this is not working with out javscript  Here is a direct working page http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/tests/templates/artificial/index.html  click to see the image, click again to see the html

Answer (score 1):

In your ASPX page, put the following:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.print();" value="Print" id="btnPrint" />
```

That creates a button that prints the webpage when you click it. Then, in your `<head>`, add the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

That will apply the `print.css` file *only* when printing. Create a file called print.css and add the following content:

```
body
{
    background-image: url('watermark.jpg') no-repeat center;
}
#btnPrint
{
    display: none;
}
```

Obviously, change `watermark.jpg` to be the name of the file you want to use as a watermark in the background.

**IN SUM:** You have created a print button and have assured that when your webpage is printed, it will use `watermark.jpg` as its background.

**UPDATE:**

As noted below, backgrounds do not print by default. The user would have to change their browser's print settings. So you should find a different way to show your watermark using text or an `<img>` element. The above code still shows you how to apply CSS only when printing.

Comment: You may also want to add to print.css to not print the actual button.

Comment: @Nick: Good point. I updated accordingly.

Comment: @Justin Satyr <asp:Button /> oh i need it as an image so that i could do watermark..