# Get webpage height

Tags: c#, .net

I try to get a screenshot of the Web Page.

So I need to know the document height.

Any clue where I can get it to apply?

Thank you!

```
private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                WebBrowser m_WebBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
                m_WebBrowser.ClientSize = new Size(this.m_BrowserWidth, this.m_BrowserHeight);
                m_WebBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(m_WebBrowser.Bounds.Width, ?????); 
                m_WebBrowser.BringToFront();
                m_WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap(m_Bitmap, m_WebBrowser.Bounds);

            }
```

Comment: [Capturing webpage as image in c#, ensuring javascript rendered elements are visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803201/capturing-webpage-as-image-in-c-ensuring-javascript-rendered-elements-are-visi)

Comment: @L.B. Put is pls like an answer.

Comment: Peretz,  Upvote it if you liked it.