# Generate JPEG from Html Content In Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to Generate Image (JPEG) from  HTML Code Entered in Textarea or other Input Controls (Not Whole Web page) using C# in **Asp.Net MVC** .**MVC doesn't Support WebBrowser Control.**

This HTML contains both data and image

**HTML**

```
<b>Convert Html To Image<b> 
<br/>
<img src="C:\Logo.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

I passed the html code to the Controller for the  Bitmap Image Creating Function

```
private Bitmap CreateBitmapImage(string html)
{
   Bitmap objBmpImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);

   int intWidth = 0;
   int intHeight = 0;

   // Create the Font object for the image text drawing.
   Font objFont = new Font("Arial", 20, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold,  System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

   // Create a graphics object to measure the text's width and height.
   Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

   // This is where the bitmap size is determined.
   intWidth = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(html, objFont).Width;
   intHeight = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(html, objFont).Height;

   // Create the bmpImage again with the correct size for the text and font.
   objBmpImage = new Bitmap(objBmpImage, new Size(intWidth, intHeight));

   // Add the colors to the new bitmap.
   objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

   // Set Background color
   objGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
   objGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
   objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
   objGraphics.DrawString(html, objFont, new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(102, 102, 102)), 0, 0);
   objGraphics.Flush();
   return (objBmpImage);
}
```

But it return the Output Like this

[image]

**But Required OutPut**

[image]

Is there any way to Generate this(Stepes to Generate Image from html) or any third party Opensource Component Available like [HtmlToImageConverter](http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToImage.aspx) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803201/capturing-webpage-as-image-in-c-ensuring-javascript-rendered-elements-are-visi or http://awesomium.com/

Comment: @ I4V thank u for ur reply i don't want to use third party .net component and IECapt doesn't support all browser

Comment: @Prabu only one "browser" needs to be supported, right? Or do you want to generate several JPEGs, one for each browser emulator?

Comment: @Prabu: I'm curious as to what you think the DrawString method actually does? The method name itself says that it draws a string. No where does it imply that it would parse a string as html, download any images in the html, and then render it all out like a webpage.

Comment: Another option may be to convert to pdf using itextsharp

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to render HTML to image with 
[HtmlRenderer](https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) dll.
You can get it in 
[HtmlRenderer.WinForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.WinForms) NuGet package (it'll also install 
[HtmlRenderer.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.Core))

There is a list of [issues](https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) about it, but it works.
You can do something like

```
public static Image RenderToImage<T>(String fullViewName, T model)
{
    String html = RenderViewToString(fullViewName, model);
    var image = HtmlRender.RenderToImage(html);
    return image;
}

public static String RenderViewToString<T>(String fullViewName, T model)
{
    String viewText = File.ReadAllText(fullViewName);
    String renderedText = Razor.Parse(viewText, model); // RazorEngine here. I don't have MVC
    return renderedText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[webSupergoo](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-html.htm) generate jpg from html. It is not open source but free to download You may also convert html to pdf  if it may solve your problem using [itextsharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/203481/HTML-convert-to-PDF-using-itextsharp)

Comment: thank u for ur respone but its not solved my pbm i need it for Our Business Card Design website..(user Customize the layout as per requirement then they save it(saved image Url store in database))