# Taking a Screen shot of WebPage using Windows Application

Tags: c#, browser

I want to take a screen shot of list of websites and save them
i have got and completed the code which i have got it from here in [StackFlow from LB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7803330/2060519)
that exact code does awesome job.
I am able to get the full Page.but there is a problem in that
I want to take images of [these](http://www.lg.com/au/washing-machines/lg-WD14022D6) and [many](http://www.lg.com/au/fridges) such websites.they load really late(or load only when you scroll to those areas of the page)
they take long time to load and some times they load only when you scroll to that area of page.
I ma using default webrowser of .net
so if i take a screenshot it will take before the page is completely loaded.
  checking the `PageComplete` event is not helping in this case. As it is showing completed event thought the images are still in loading stage.
`Sleep` is also not helping.

---

Cant use third party tools. so please help me. i saw many links for that and cant use or pay for them
does any one has any idea?? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a third party library called Selenium to wait for specific elements in the DOM to load before taking your screenshot. This library is normally used for automated testing of webpage user interfaces. More details can be found [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

Selenium is capable of working with different browser types (you did not specify which browser you are working with in your question), so you will need to do some further research based on this. Searching for something along the lines of "Selenium element visibility" with your browser type will lead you to the required functions.

Comment: as mentioned in the tag. i am using default .net webbrowser. third party is currently not an option as my company will not pay.

Comment: but i will look to selenium

Comment: Selenium uses the Apache 2.0 licence - meaning that it is freeware. Please refer to their licence page [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/license.jsp "http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/license.jsp")